# How to fix pod install error glog is too old or missing react native ios on MacOS

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

Trying to get my project to build however when running `pod install` I run into a list of errors stating a glog script is too old or is missing.

```
set -e

PLATFORM_NAME="${PLATFORM_NAME:-iphoneos}"
CURRENT_ARCH="${CURRENT_ARCH}"

if [ -z "$CURRENT_ARCH" ] || [ "$CURRENT_ARCH" == "undefined_arch" ]; then
    # Xcode 10 beta sets CURRENT_ARCH to "undefined_arch", this leads to incorrect linker arg.
    # it's better to rely on platform name as fallback because architecture differs between simulator and device

    if [[ "$PLATFORM_NAME" == *"simulator"* ]]; then
        CURRENT_ARCH="x86_64"
    else
        CURRENT_ARCH="arm64"
    fi
fi

export CC="$(xcrun -find -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME cc) -arch $CURRENT_ARCH -isysroot $(xcrun -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME --show-sdk-path)"
export CXX="$CC"

# Remove automake symlink if it exists
if [ -h "test-driver" ]; then
    rm test-driver
fi

./configure --host arm-apple-darwin

cat << EOF >> src/config.h
/* Add in so we have Apple Target Conditionals */
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <TargetConditionals.h>
#include <Availability.h>
#endif

/* Special configuration for ucontext */
#undef HAVE_UCONTEXT_H
#undef PC_FROM_UCONTEXT
#if defined(__x86_64__)
#define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__rip
#elif defined(__i386__)
#define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__eip
#endif
EOF

# Prepare exported header include
EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR="exported/glog"
mkdir -p exported/glog
cp -f src/glog/log_severity.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/raw_logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/stl_logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/vlog_is_on.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"

checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-apple-darwin-strip... /Users/carlos/opt/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for arm-apple-darwin-gcc... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk
checking whether the C compiler works... no
/Users/carlos/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/glog/2263bd123499e5b93b5efe24871be317-53372/missing: Unknown `--is-lightweight' option
Try `/Users/carlos/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/glog/2263bd123499e5b93b5efe24871be317-53372/missing --help' for more information
configure: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing
configure: error: in `/Users/carlos/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/glog/2263bd123499e5b93b5efe24871be317-53372':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

we are running react native version 0.65.1 and the Podfile is below

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'FanbasisRN' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )



  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

  pod 'react-native-twilio-video-webrtc', path: '../node_modules/react-native-twilio-video-webrtc'








  target 'FanbasisRNTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|

    react_native_post_install(installer)

    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
    end
  end

end
```

I've tried several fixes but none of them have worked so far
`sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app`
removing some pods
along with changing in package.json
`"start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start"`
I am also running these on an Intel mac so all the M1 workarounds have also not been working
Any help you guys can provide would be greatly appreciated.